# Django - Ajax without JQuery lib

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

I am Learning and using Ajax without jQuery Lib. I created a simple view which renders a random number on to the template. I added a button and called the ajax function. However, clicking the button doesn't change the value on the screen. I checked in DOM (firebug) and it shows the someText.responseText is yielding the whole html rather than just the value, however it has the new value in that HTML. I am sharing this to provide more information on what I have found so far. I am new to this and experimented it with a lot for ex; I have checked  "request.is_ajax():" but somehow the view does not find ajax in request. I have printed request on command line and the GET querydict is empty.

Obviously I am not doing something in the correct manner for Django. Please assist.

I have a view;

```
def home(request):
    rand_num = random.randint(1,100)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'rand_num':rand_num})
```

and html and script;

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var someText;
    function helloWorld(){
        someText = new XMLHttpRequest();
        someText.onreadystatechange = callBack;

        someText.open("GET", "{% url 'home' %}", true);
        someText.send();
    };

    // When information comes back from the server.
    function callBack(){
        if(someText.readyState==4 && someText.status==200){
            document.getElementById('result').innerHtml = someText.responseText;
        }
    };
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="result">{{rand_num}}</div>
<input type='button' value='Abraca dabra!' onclick="helloWorld()"/>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the url for this view;

```
url(r'^$', 'socialauth.views.home', name='home'),
```

I am learning this from an online tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

That is because your AJAX endpoint is the whole view -  I.e. your AJAX request asks for the whole rendered template.

What you want is just a number, so make a new view and URL to return just the number, and make the AJAX request to that.

AJAX isn't anything special, its just a way to make an asynchronous request to a URL and get the contents returned.

For reference, a view using something like JSONResponse:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_random_number_json(request):
    random_no = random.randint(1,100)
    return JsonResponse({'random_no': random_no})
```

Then in your frontend Javascript, fetch url for that view, which will give you only the JSON in your javascript variable via your AJAX call, and instead of all that `document.getElementById('result')` processing, you can just grab the variable from the json object.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also thought so and tried taking info out but was unable to. Can you suggest something on this. Also, even if I get the value I think the value will still not render on the page since in the current scenario possibly it should have rendered the whole html page. Is that correct?

Comment: Don't take info out, just make a second view and URL which gives you the info you need - basically an HTTPResponse object with just the value in the body.

Comment: Thanks, I am struggling with it however, don't want you to write the whole code. Thanks anyway. I will see what I can do with it.

Comment: I've fleshed out a bit of information, the rest you can gather from the Django docs, and Javascript examples for AJAX requests.